# Multiple encryption news shown in messages

Tags: whatsapp

I recently upgraded to the last version of Whatsapp.
In some chat It shows encryption news several time (3-4 time on the same chat).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a group it will show once per member of the group. If it's a regular conversation I have no clue